# Having type A with N fields is it possible to merge it into new object of type B with N+x fields?

Tags: c, struct

Say we have an instance of

```
struct Message {
    char * topic;
    int topicLength;

    void * data;
    int dataLength;
};
```

and we want to recreate it as an object of other type

```
struct CoreMessage {
    int messaageId;

    char * topic;
    int topicLength;

    void * data;
    int dataLength;

    char * senderId;
    int senderIdLength;
};
```

Can we safly turn `Message A` into `CoreMessage B`? thing in C without copying contents, having types partly overlaping as shown here?

Comment: Showing a sample of how code has an "instance of `struct Message`" would help.  Depending on  that code, various solutions exists.

Comment: To do what you're asking, there has to be unused storage on both sides of the object -- so you can't do this on arrays of the original type, just one-offs.  If you ever find a situation where this is actually worth doing, assembly language is the right answer.  It's going to be _extremely_ special-purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do what you ask.  You could come close, however, if you were willing to change the layout of `struct CoreMessage` like so:

```
struct CoreMessage {
    struct Message message;

    int messaageId;

    char * senderId;
    int senderIdLength;
};
```

Note that `struct CoreMessage` then contains an actual `struct Message` as a member (as opposed to a pointer to one).  Then, given ...

```
struct CoreMessage cm;
struct CoreMessage *cmp = &cm;
struct Message *mp = &cm.message;
```

... you have `(void *) cmp == (void *) mp`, which can be useful for some of the kinds of things you might want to do.  This is also adjusts automatically to changes to `struct Message`.

Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
struct Message {
    char * topic;
    int topicLength;

    void * data;
    int dataLength;

    maximum_alignment_requirement_t resv1;
    char resv2[AS_MANY_BYTES_AS_ANY_MESSAGE_TYPE_MAY_NEED_INCLUDING_PADDING];
};

struct CoreMessage {
    char * topic;
    int topicLength;

    void * data;
    int dataLength;

    maximum_alignment_requirement_t resv1;

    int messaageId;

    char * senderId;
    int senderIdLength;
};

struct Message msg;
struct CoreMessage *cmp = (struct CoreMessage *) &msg;
```

That has a high probability of working as you would hope (and some system interfaces work pretty much this way) but C does not *guarantee* that those corresponding elements will be laid out the same way in the two different `struct` types.

Note, too, that it was no accident that I moved `CoreMessage.messageId` after the members corresponding to those of `struct Message`.  It is much harder to arrange for corresponding layout if you do not do this, and the pointer value equivalence of the first alternative depends on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can fake this with anonymous structures/unions. Anonymous structures have admittedly only been standardized since `C11` but many popular compilers have supported them as an extension for ages.

That is something along these, admittedly-less-than-pretty, lines:

```
struct Message  {
    char * topic;
    int topicLength;
    void * data;
    int dataLength;
    char * senderId;
    int senderIdLength;
};

struct CoreMessage {
    int messageId;
    union {
        struct Message;
        struct Message message;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "safely turn", but I would expect the answer to be "no". The structures are different, of course the smaller one can't magically be expected to expand into memory it didn't previously use.

There is no concept of "overlapping types" in C.

You can of course declare `CoreMessage` in terms of `Message`, but it won't help for the reverse transform from the smaller to the larger type except by making the transfer of the shared information easier:

```
struct CoreMessage {
  int messageId;
  struct Message message;
  char *senderId;
  int senderIdLength;
};
```

Now if we have:

```
struct Message a = { ... }; /* fully initialized */
struct CoreMessage b; /* we want to convert Message into this */
```

we can do:

```
b.messageId = 4711;
b.message = a; /* Copy all Message data over. */
b.senderId = "foo";
b.senderIdLength = 3;
```

Nothing is automatic here though, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: The fact of Copying is what I hoped to escape..(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "turn into".  I'm not sure how you can get casting to do this for you.

But, the C standard allows the compiler to put unused space between fields of a struct so, in general nothing would really work.  You could make "CoreMessage" contain a "Message" and produce your result with a single assignment.